# Do I need to install babel to be able to write ES6 code in my react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, create-react-app

I created a react app and started trying to connect it to a server I have prepared using MongoDB. Whenever I check my localhost to see the react app, the error "expression expected" keeps appearing although my code seems to be correct.

I created a file called http-service.js with the code found below.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

class HttpService {
    getProducts = () = > {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/product')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.json());
    })
    }
}

export default HttpService;
```

Then I imported it to my App.js file which can be seen below.

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import HttpService from "../services/http-service";

const http = new HttpService();

function App() {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      http.getProducts();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Welcome to The Swag Shop
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDx5S.png) shows the problems shown in the console.

How should I address this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors here:

1- In your `HttpService` file you have a syntax error in your arrow function, a space between `=` and `>`, it should be like this:

```js
class HttpService {
    getProducts = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/product')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.json());
    })
    }
}

export default HttpService;
```

2- in `App.js` you defined a **constructor** in a normal function, that is no valid in javascript, you have to either to switch `App.js` from function to class or you can use hooks **(useEffect)** in your normal function, Something like this:

```js
 React.useEffect(() => {
    http.getProducts();
  }, [])
```

Finally with create-react-app u are, [babel is already included](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html) so you can use ES6 in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I decided switch from function to a class. This removed the errors. However, it still fails to GET data from my mongoDB when I run it using Postman. Getting data worked before, back when I didn't link my localhost:3000 yet to my react-app. Do you happen to know the possible source of error?

Comment: @David which port your react and mongoDB services are using?

Comment: They are in the same port 3000. Should I change my mongoDB's port?

Comment: @David yes, and don't forget to update your react url to the updated mongoDB url

Comment: I changed my API's port to localhost:3001 (which means the data are in localhost:3001/products) and tested fetching data with Postman. It worked. However, changing the fetch() of my http-services.js to the localhost:3001 still failed . The following error was shown: 


"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/product' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. "

Comment: @David this is normal because they are running on different ports (different origins) the solution is enabling your back end service to allow different origin

Comment: I downloaded the chrome extension Allow CORS to let the browser gain permission to access resources from a server on a different domain.

Answer (score 3):

In your arrow function, you have a space between `=` and `>`. So pls correct it.

Also, if you are using create-react-app, babel is already installed for you out of the box.

**Like this**

```js
import 'whatwg-fetch';

class HttpService {
    getProducts = () => { // remove space between = and >
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/product')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.json());
    })
    }
}

export default HttpService;
```

Comment: Thank you for that reminder. It helped! The only error left is the ' ; ' expected in my App.js. I do not understand where it wants the semi-colon.